# JSON.simple API Javadoc

Tags: json, javadoc, json-simple

Is there a Javadoc for JSON.simple?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I generated the Javadoc from source and [put it online](http://alex-public-doc.s3.amazonaws.com/json_simple-1.1/index.html).

The project wiki has [some interesting pages](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/w/list) and version 1.0.2 also had an interesting [README](http://json-simple.googlecode.com/svn/tags/tag_release_1_0_2/README.txt).

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful. Although the README file and wiki pages on Google Code are pretty much exhaustive for such a simple library, it's still helpful to have the JavaDoc.

Comment: Thank you! This is still a good javadoc. With version 1.1.1, there are some chinese/japanese characters in the doc which makes it absolutely unreadable. Possibly because issue#108 (https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/issues)